# Unknown website after creating website using appcmd

Tags: iis, appcmd

I am using IIS 8.5 (Windows 8.1). I tried to create a website to my local IIS using the `appcmd` tool.
I used those pages as reference (I know they are for IIS 7 but I couldn't find the equivalent for IIS 8):

- [Create a Web Application (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Create a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Here is the command I used:

```
appcmd add site /name:fakeAbsorbApi /physicalPath:C:\development\ecms\build\deploy\fakeAbsorbApi /bindings:http:/*:9898
```

I receive [the following feeedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oseg9.png):

```
SITE object "fakeAbsorbApi" added
APP object "fakeAbsorbApi/" added
VDIR object fakeAbsorbApi/" added
```

but if I check my IIS Manager, it shows the website as "unknown," and I can't do anything with it. (It seems that the web config is not being detected)

[image: Screenshot of IIS Manager with "X" on new website]

I tried to create the same website using the same parameters via IIS Manager (pointing to the very same folder) and the website it created works perfectly.

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey it looks like you have an extra colon on the bindings flag. Also you need to add a host header after the port number. I fixed it below.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd add site /name:fakeAbsorbApi /physicalPath:C:\development\ecms\build\deploy\fakeAbsorbApi /bindings:http/*:9898:www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not include an Application Pool in your arguments, `appcmd` may choose the "DefaultAppPool" for you. If that app pool does not exist, the site will be created in the "Unknown" state.